# Jquery AJAX extract session from one ajax call and use it in a second ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is a scenario

- Lets say I am working on a website called www.example.com, where i have logged in and have JSESSION and SESSIONID cookies created from www.example.com
- from one of the pages in www.example.com I want to make an ajax post call to www.secondexample.com which is actually a login to www.secondexample.com and then make a second ajax call www.secondexample.com using the logged in session from first call to www.secondexample.com.

I did a lot of search but could not find how to use session when making an ajax call.

Comment: I'm trying to understand clearly your scenario. You want to send a request from a domain to another, in this "new" domain you will log in. OK. Your second call must be a new request from a success callback received from the first. You want to call it again sending logged in user data? To test the login rules? Why not a JSON (maybe encrypted) forgetting the session?

Comment: AJAX will use the existing cookies with that server it's connecting to. You can't control the cookies explicitly.